# How to import react framework into vscode source code project to create UI component?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, architecture, frameworks

When i customize vscode source code, i found it hard to add a page.

I know there are many ways to do so, such as `Part/Widget/Browserwindow`, but only if i new a `Browserwindow` can i explicitly load html and js files like in chrome browser and it's friendly.

If i use a `Part` or a `Widget`, i need to use native js api to do dom manipulation, and it's so inefficient,

~~so i want to know how did vscode team decide to use no ui framework during the development? Is there some trade-off?~~

i tried to import `react` and `react-dom` directly in my own contrib file  `/vs/workbench/contrib/dialog/browser/dialog.ts`, and then get successful compilation and the react component shows up, but i don't know how to add babel with the compilation procedure, so i use react without jsx.

so i want to know how to import react framework into vscode source code project to create ui component? Is there some practices?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only the development team can answer you

Comment: vscode team's answer is expected, actually i intended to post it on github, but it says issue tracker is not for questions and ask questions here.

Comment: This is place for specific programming problems. Asking why some product uses this or that technology is off topic here. Please visit [help] to learn what kind of questions are appropriate here.

Comment: ok, i change the question to How